# Cómo Pasar un Jframe a otra clase y reutilizar el mismo Jframe

Tags: java

¿Cómo paso un diseño de un `Jframe` ya elaborado con sus objetos o componentes a otro `Jframe` del mismo paquete y reutilizarlo en otra clase?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a crear otra *instancia* de ese mismo `JFrame`, es decir, otra *instancia* de la misma clase?

Comment: Exacto como seria

Answer (score 2):

Hice un ejemplo donde tenemos dos clases y uno clase pasa un JFrame través de un método. También se puede pasar el JFrame a través del constructor.

En Clase1, tenemos el método que acepta un JFrame de otra clase y almacenarlo en una variable.

En Clase2, creamos el JFrame, crear un objeto de Clase1, y pasar nuestra JFrame.

```
    import java.io.*;

    public Clase1 {
        JFrame variable;

        public void agregarJFrame(JFrame j) {
            variable = j;
        }
    }



    import java.io.*;

    public Clase2 {
        public static main void(String[] args) {
            Clase1 obj = new Clase1();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            //El método necesita un argumento, el Jframe.
            obj.agregarJFrame(frame);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Me sirvio tu respuesta muchas Gracias....

Comment: mmmmmm.... porque no usar directamente el metodo `frame.add(child);`? aparte, el metodo `agregarJFrame` es simplemente un setter, mejor seguir las convenciones con el nombre...

Answer (score 1):

SI lo querés hacer como una plantilla siempre idéntica podes crear una interfaz,una vez que llamás a la interfaz le asignas ese JFrame a otro que va  a ser tu definitivo de esa clase. Donde podés jugar y hacerle lo que quieras sin tener que tocar el que está definido en la interfaz.

**Interfaz con el JFrame de plantilla**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/*      Como plantilla      */
public interface JFrameImplements {

    public static JFrame plantillaJFrame() {

        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
        JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();
        jpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel jlabel = new JLabel("Texto");

        JButton jbutton = new JButton("Boton");

        jframe.add(jpanel);
        jpanel.add(jlabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jpanel.add(jbutton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        jframe.setBounds(100, 100, 250, 150);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        return jframe;
    }

}
```

**Clase que lo implementa**
En qué nos Beneficia usar una interfaz en este caso? en que podemos implementar muchas más interfaces y a su vez dejamos la posibilidad de seguir teniendo la opción de extender de otra Clase que no sea JFrame, ya que si la extendemos de la misma, no la vamos a poder extender de otra.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JFrame1 implements JFrameImplements {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame jframe = JFrameImplements.plantillaJFrame();

        /*  Acá ya accedimos a todos los atributos del JFrame definido en la interfaz   */
        jframe.setBounds(100, 100, 560, 500);

    }
}
```

**Otra clase que lo implementa, deja la posibilidad de extender de una clase como Thread u otra.**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JFrame2 implements JFrameImplements {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame jframe = JFrameImplements.plantillaJFrame();

        /*  Acá ya accedimos a todos los atributos del JFrame definido en la interfaz   */
        jframe.setBounds(100, 100, 320, 210);
        jframe.setTitle("Esta es otra plantilla que estoy modificando y hago lo que quiero sin extender de una clase padre");

    }
}
```

Comment: @bwalshy espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que te sugiero seria crear los frame pero seria modificar las propiedades del segundo frama para que en el primero crees un objeto del mismo y desde hay puedas llamar a sus elementos y le asignes los valores que tiene el primero, al momento de dar clic todo lo que este en el primero y halla sido asignado a los elementos del segundo frame se visualizara.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlYiP57A8pk

Comment: Muchas gracias Muy Oportuna tu respuesta..

Answer (score 0):

Crea una clase padre y extiéndela a las clases JFrame_A y JFrame_B donde tendrás los JFrame que quieres , en el constructor del padre creas todos los componentes, y de esta forma los JFrame A y B estarán iguales, en el constructor de los JFrame A y B puedes crear componentes que solo los hijos tendrán.

Nos podrías dar un poco mas de contexto de que es lo que quieres hacer para poder darte una mejor respuesta o puede ser que te ayudemos de otras formas.